# Running Ajax request not working

Tags: ajax

I just migrated to a different bootstrap template now my ajax functions is not working and my php file which handles the functions is not appearing in the XHR inspect tool of chrome. 
I only have this jquery script ? is this enough for running an ajax function? I

```
<!-- Jquery Core Js -->
<script src="../dashboard-assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

HTML CODE

```
<form id="upload_book_form" method="POST">
<p>Upload Books</p>
<input type="file" id="uploadbookinfo" name="uploadbookinfo" value="Import" />
</form>
```

SCRIPT FUNCTION

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //upload book
        $('#uploadbookinfo').change(function() {
            $('#upload_book_form').submit();
        });
        $('#upload_book_form').on('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "adminfunctions.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    var getdata = data.trim();
                    if (getdata == "SUCCESS") {
                        swal({
                            title: 'Success!',
                            text: 'Book Added , Try refreshing the page',
                            type: 'success',
                            confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-success",
                            buttonsStyling: false
                        }).then(function() {
                            $("#uploadbookinfo").val(null);
                        });
                    } else if (getdata == "ERRORFILETYPE") {
                        swal({
                            title: 'Oops...',
                            text: 'File type is not supported',
                            type: 'error',
                            confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-danger",
                            buttonsStyling: false
                        }).then(function() {
                            $("#uploadbookinfo").val(null);
                        });
                    } else {
                        swal({
                            title: 'Sorry for the inconvenience!',
                            text: "There's a problem. Please contact the technical support for any concerns and questions.!",
                            type: 'error',
                            confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-info",
                            buttonsStyling: false
                        }).then(function() {
                            $("#uploadbookinfo").val(null);
                        });
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, it's enough. Provide your code if you want somebody to help you.

Comment: @htshame I provided the code can you check it?